# How to catch the "fn+" key in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I couldn't find a way to catch the event when fn+ another key is pressed. I could only catch other keys and the alt, ctrl and shift key.

Answer (score 1):

How to capture a pressed function key and then perform an action on a Windows application
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822492

I'm assuming your using winforms, remember that you can detect the key press on a Form. Simply set the Forms KeyPreview to True and put the code in the KB article into the Forms KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
'When the function keys are pressed, FuncKeysModule is called. 
 If e.KeyValue = Keys.F1 Or Keys.F2 Or Keys.F3 Or Keys.F4 Or Keys.F5 Or Keys.F6 Or Keys.F7  Or Keys.F8 Or Keys.F9 Or Keys.F10 Or Keys.F11 Or Keys.F12 Then
     FuncKeysModule(e.KeyValue)
     e.Handled = True
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Becareful this solution is for F1, F2 ... F12 keys not for the FN key.

Answer (score 0):

Not like `ctrl`, `alt`, and `shift`, `Fn` is not a standard modifier key.

Say `Fn+F2` means mute on my keyboard, it means there is a `KEY` called sth like `XF86MUTE`.

When pressing `alt+a`, the system gets exactly "Alt + a".
When pressing `Fn+F2`, the system gets an `XF86MUTE`.
When pressing `Fn+a`, the system only gets an `a`.